# Radio button label not next to label—how to fix?

Tags: html, css

### Problem

[image]

If you run my code you'll see that my `radio labels` don't align with my `radio input`, and I'm not sure why since I put the `radio input` in the `label` tag. I also tried removing the `row` class from the `radio input` `label`, but that didn't work.

If anyone could tell me how I can align the `radio input` with its `label` that would be great!

### Code

#### HTML

```
<label class="row">
            <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-high" checked="checked">
            <h2 class="priority-high">High</h2> </label>
        <label class="row">
            <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-medium">
            <h2 class="priority-medium">Medium</h2> </label>
        <label class="row">
            <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-low">
            <h2 class="priority-low">Low</h2> </label>
```

#### CSS

```
/*Add task styling*/

input[name="title"] {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 2em;
}

select[name="course"],
input[name="due-date"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

input[name="note"] {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    width: 100%;
}

input[name="due-date"] {
    width: 130px;
}

.error {
    color: #d11141;
}


/*Task styling*/

.task {
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
}

.task-title {
    padding-top: 2.5%;
}

.checkbox,
button[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
}

.checkbox {
    background-color: #fafafb;
}

.task-info {
    float: right;
}

.task-info h2 {
    display: inline;
}

.task-info input[name="priority"] {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.task-info input[name="due-date"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.due-date {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

.priority {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.priority-high {
    color: #d11141;
}

.priority-medium {
    color: #ffc425;
}

.priority-low {
    color: #00aedb;
}

.task-details {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 4.5%;
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;
}

.task-date {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.note {
    padding-top: 1%;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

### Snippet

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300i,400,400i');

/*General styling*/

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #333333;
    margin: 0 3% 0 3%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
}

.row {
    display: block;
}

.col {
    display: inline-block;
}

.search,
.task {
    background-color: #fafafb;
}

div.element:first-child {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.element {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/*Remove auto styling*/

button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #fafafb;
    color: #333333;
    padding: 0;
}

button:focus,
input:focus,
select:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
    margin: 0;
}


/*General form  styling*/

input[type="text"],
select[name="course"],
input[name="due-date"] {
    background-color: #fafafb;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333333;
    border: none;
}

input[type="submit"],
button {
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #949496;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="note"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]:-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

input[type="text"][name="due-date"]::-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: 300;
}

button[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.7em;
}


/*Search bar styling*/

.search {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

.search-header {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#search,
#show-all {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#search {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#show-all {
    font-size: 2em;
}

input[name="search"] {
    width: 80%;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 50px;
}

.search-header button[type="button"] {
    float: right;
}

.search-header #arrow {
    font-size: 3em;
}

.search-details {
    margin-left: 4%;
}

.search-details h2 {
    display: inline;
}

.search-details .priority,
.search-details input[name="note"] {
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.search-details input[name="note"] {
    width: 85%;
}

.search-details .priority {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.search-details label {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}


/*Add task styling*/

input[name="title"] {
    width: 70%;
    font-size: 2em;
}

select[name="course"],
input[name="due-date"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

input[name="note"] {
    font-size: 1.15em;
    width: 100%;
}

input[name="due-date"] {
    width: 130px;
}

.error {
    color: #d11141;
}


/*Task styling*/

.task {
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
}

.task-title {
    padding-top: 2.5%;
}

.checkbox,
button[type="submit"] {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
}

.checkbox {
    background-color: #fafafb;
}

.task-info {
    float: right;
}

.task-info h2 {
    display: inline;
}

.task-info input[name="priority"] {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.task-info input[name="due-date"] {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.due-date {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

.priority {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

.priority-high {
    color: #d11141;
}

.priority-medium {
    color: #ffc425;
}

.priority-low {
    color: #00aedb;
}

.task-details {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-left: 4.5%;
    padding-bottom: 2.5%;
}

.task-date {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.note {
    padding-top: 1%;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<form action="index.php" class="task row element" method="post" name="add-task">
        <div class="task-title row">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" class="col"><span class="icon-add" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <input type="text" class="col" name="title" placeholder="Add a task...">
            <div class="task-info">
                <h3 class="error">*Task field cannot be empty</h3>
                <input type="text" class="due-date col" name="due-date" placeholder="Due date"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="task-details">
            <h2>Priority</h2>
            <label class="row">
                <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-high" checked="checked">
                <h2 class="priority-high">High</h2> </label>
            <label class="row">
                <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-medium">
                <h2 class="priority-medium">Medium</h2> </label>
            <label class="row">
                <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-low">
                <h2 class="priority-low">Low</h2> </label>
            <div class="row">
                <select name="course" class="col">
                    <option value="CS-2043">CS 2043</option>
                    <option value="CS-2300">CS 2300</option>
                    <option value="CS-3420">CS 3420</option>
                    <option value="CS-4820">CS 4820</option>
                    <option value="CS-4998">CS 4998</option>
                    <option value="HADM-2230" selected>HADM 2230</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" class="note col" name="note" placeholder="Add a note...">
                <h3 class="error">*Note field cannot be empty</h3> </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I do think it is a good practice to put heading element inside label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

h1 to h6 are block-level elements which span the entire width of the line. You can change them to inline with css like this:

```
h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to put the heading element inside form label. If you need visual effect like bigger font-size using CSS instead.

Try to replace the heading element to `span` which is a inline element.

```
<lable>
  <span>Label</span>
  <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-high" checked="checked">
</label>
```

For your own good, please avoid using inline style.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
<div class="row">

  <input type="radio" name="priority" value="priority-high" checked="checked" style="display: inline-block;">
  <h2 class="priority-high" style="display: inline-block;">High</h2> 
</div>
```